# How to notify with SNMP that an error was solved. Traps?

Tags: snmp-trap

Using SNMP I can create traps (notifications). In effect, these are notifications that an error situation occurred.

But how do I notify that a situation returned to normal? 
Can I somehow 'train' systems like PTRG or Zabbix to interpret one trap as a 'set' and another trap as a 'reset'?

Or should I be using another mechanism to achieve this? Are traps only used to notify error situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any well-designed TRAP/NOTIFICATION that indicates a problem comes in a pair that indicates that the problem is resolved, eg. linkUp/linkDown, *ThresholdExceeded/*ThresholdNormal, etc. If it does not come in a pair, that's usually an indication that there could be too many occurrences of the TRAPs. Also, a TRAP is only an indication of something, its resolution usually involves inquiring many variables to determine the exact root cause, then some actions. If you have an exact condition you need to monitor, you need to detail.

Comment: The above answer is the correct one. One alternative approach that I've seen often in the wild is to have each alarm trap contain an alarm number and a  "severity" value. When the fault is solved, it re-sends the same trap, with the same alarm number and the severity "cleared". The SNMP Manager should then clear/remove the alarm from its list of active alarms. This is slightly less easy to implement for a manager application, but is more flexible as having alarm numbers permits several active alarms for the same trap. Use whichever models the equipment best.